# matplotlib gives a ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame. The columns, head and dtypes are as shown below:

```
print sorted_results.dtypes
print sorted_results[['coefficients']].head()

0                object
coefficients    float64
dtype: object
     coefficients
62       2.432853
70       2.187059
19       1.804636
68       1.507075
130      1.120488
```

I want to plot a barchart using matplot lib, so

```
plt.barh(range(len(sorted_results)), sorted_results[['coefficients']])
```

gives the following:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1d344a50d686> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 plt.barh(range(len(sorted_results)), sorted_results[['coefficients']])

/Users/sram/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in barh(bottom, width, height, left, hold, **kwargs)
   2665         ax.hold(hold)
   2666     try:
-> 2667         ret = ax.barh(bottom, width, height=height, left=left, **kwargs)
   2668     finally:
   2669         ax.hold(washold)

/Users/sram/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in barh(self, bottom, width, height, left, **kwargs)
   2245 
   2246         patches = self.bar(left=left, height=height, width=width,
-> 2247                            bottom=bottom, orientation='horizontal', **kwargs)
   2248         return patches
   2249 

/Users/sram/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1817                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1818                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1820         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1821         if pre_doc is None:

/Users/sram/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, **kwargs)
   2085                 edgecolor=e,
   2086                 linewidth=lw,
-> 2087                 label='_nolegend_'
   2088                 )
   2089             r.update(kwargs)

/Users/sram/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.pyc in __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)
    640         self._x = float(xy[0])
    641         self._y = float(xy[1])
--> 642         self._width = float(width)
    643         self._height = float(height)
    644         self._angle = float(angle)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: coefficients
```

Coefficients seems to have the right datatype. I'm stumped by why I am doing wrong here

Comment: Looks like it's trying to convert the name of your column `coefficients` to float. What happens if you use `sorted_results[['coefficients']].values` in your plot command?

Comment: dang. Thanks, you are right Khris. Happy to mark this as the correct answer if you write it up